# How to get all query parameters from go *gin.context object

Tags: go, go-gin

I am looking at `https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin` documentation for a method which returns list of all the query parameters passed. There are methods which return value of a query parameter. Is there any method which returns list of all the query parameters passed ? It's ok if we don't get values. I am fetching the values of the query parameter using the following code. But this code can only check if the query parameter exists or not.

```
func myHandler(c *gin.Context) {

    // check for query params
    if queryParam, ok := c.GetQuery("startingIndex"); ok {
        if queryParam == "" {
            c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound,
                gin.H{"Error: ": "Invalid startingIndex on search filter!"})
            c.Abort()
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You should be able to do `c.Request.URL.Query()` which will return a [Values](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Query) which is a `map[string][]string`

Comment: why choose map[string][]string instead of map[string]string?

Comment: In a query string, a param name can be used more than once, using []string for the value of the map allows them to capture all of different values that share the same param name. https://play.golang.org/p/FtQIz_ePF_N

Answer (score 29):

you can get query parameters using :

```
c.Query("key") -> returns string
or
c.GetQuery("key") -> returns (string, bool->ok)
```

Answer (score 18):

If you're talking about GET query params, you can retrieve them using:

```
c.Request.URL.Query()
```

You'll get back a Values type which is a `map[string][]string`

Docs: https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Query

Answer (score 0):

Carrying on from @ctcherry's answer...

```
func myAPIEndpoint(c *gin.Context) {

    paramPairs := c.Request.URL.Query()
    for key, values := range paramPairs {
        fmt.Printf("key = %v, value(s) = %v\n", key, values)
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that a given key may contain multiple values, so your `values` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what type is come you can use

```
ctx.GetString("string")
ctx.GetBool("bool")
ctx.GetInt("int")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value from the last part of the URL "api/abc/value". Use the .Param method that collects from the url. Don't forget to change your URL to: "api/abc/:value" (the 2 dots are very important)

code example:

```
func ReturnPersonalitie(c *gin.Context) {
    vars := c.Param("id")
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(vars)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error: ", err)
    }

    for _, personalitie := range models.Personalities {
        if personalitie.Id == id {
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, personalitie)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Value id: %d", id)
}
```

calling:

```
r.GET("/api/personalidades/:id", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
    controllers.ReturnPersonalitie(ctx)
})
```

For more information read: https://gin-gonic.com/docs/examples/param-in-path/

Comment: You're right, I'll improve next time, but I wanted to share the solution I found after coming here to this question!

Comment: ok I changed it, can you validate?